# OpenDS server not starting getting port error

Tags: java, opends

can any one can help with this?

When i am trying to install Opends got below error

> server not starting
>
> WARNING: Could not connect to server: javax.naming.CommunicationException: 0.0.0.0:4444 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException: 0.0.0.0:4444 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
>
> Could not connect to the server after requesting start. If you have a firewall configured check that it allows connections to port 4444.           org.opends.quicksetup.util.ServerController.startServer(ServerController.java:511)           org.opends.quicksetup.util.ServerController.startServer(ServerController.java:292)           org.opends.quicksetup.installer.offline.OfflineInstaller.run(OfflineInstaller.java:142)           java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when there is already an application that uses the port 4444 on the machine.

What is your platform ?

Btw, do you know that OpenDS was last released in 2010 ? You might want to look at OpenDJ for newer and more up to date versions.